# pigpio Python Raspberry Pi wave PWM generation

Tags: gpio, python, pi-4, pigpio

I am using pigpio to generate a PWM signal varying in time. I create a wave, which contains one period of a sine wave, in the form of PWM signal. I use wave_send_using_mode and WAVE_MODE_REPEAT_SYNC to get synchronisation. It works perfectly as long as I don't try to change the wave (for example with a new amplitude or period). Then it seems that there's no synchronisation, I get steps at transitions (see screenshot).

This is the PWM generation code:

```
#import necessary libraries
import pigpio
import numpy as np

#pi - pigpio instancem pin - PWM pin, frequency - sine frequency, lower - lower bound of the PWM in %, upper - upper bound of the PWM in %
def set_PWM(pi, pin, frequency, lower, upper):
    
    #create variables
    fla = []
    zero = 0

    #how many steps in a period
    bits = 1000
    #carrier frequency * 5
    carrier = 5000*5

    period = (5/frequency)/carrier * 10e6

    pi.set_mode(pin, pigpio.OUTPUT)

    amplitude = (upper - lower) / 100

    #create a profile, sine
    for i in range(bits):
        sine = ((np.sin(2*np.pi * i/bits) + 1) / 2 * amplitude) + lower / 100 
        fla.append(pigpio.pulse(1<<pin, zero, int(sine * period/2)))
        fla.append(pigpio.pulse(zero, 1<<pin, int((1-sine) * period/2)))

    #clear current waveforms
    pi.wave_clear()

    #add the created pulses to a new waveform
    pi.wave_add_generic(fla)

    #create a bew waveform
    fi = pi.wave_create()

    #send the waveform indefinitely
    pi.wave_send_using_mode(fi, pigpio.WAVE_MODE_REPEAT_SYNC)

    #check if force is ok, if not then create a new profile, and use wave_send_using_mode command with wave_mode_repeat_sync parameter
    #this will try to synchronise the previous profile with a new one, to avoid step changes of duty cycle

    #this approach doesn't block the program, something else can be done in the meanwhile

#set solenoid current to 0, pi - pigpio instance
def stop_PWM(pi):
    pi.wave_tx_stop()
```

and the code for changing PWM every 3 seconds:

```
#import necessary libraries
import pigpio
from time import sleep
import time
import numpy as np
import PWM
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#specify PWM pin
pin = 12

DRDY_PIN = 14

frequency = 1

lower = 20
upper = 80

PI_HOST = ''
pi = pigpio.pi(PI_HOST)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

while 1:
    PWM.set_PWM(pi, pin, frequency, lower, upper)
    sleep(3)
    PWM.set_PWM(pi, pin, frequency, 40, 60)
    sleep(3)
    PWM.set_PWM(pi, pin, frequency*2, lower, upper)
    sleep(3)
    PWM.set_PWM(pi, pin, frequency*2, 50, 50)
    sleep(3)
```

when I look up the generated output, using a device which translates PWM to a proper analog signal, I get this:[image]

and sending only one wave (but repeating set_PWM function every 3 seconds):
[image]

If I just do set_PWM once, the generated waveform is a perfect sine with no transition problems.